# how to check session is no longer active on partial view in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
function EditSourcePartailView(ID, StepID, StepAction, Action) {
     $.ajax({
         url: "/Publication/NewEditDataSource" + "?StepID=" + StepID + "&ID=" + ID + "&ActionType=" + StepAction,
         dataType: "text",
         type: "POST",
         data: $("#formID").serialize(),
         success: function (data) {
              if (!data.hasError) {
                  $('#AddDatasourceDiv').html(data);
              }
         }
     });
}
```